# Trouble with showing data from database on a fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, fragment

I want to show my user name from database to the fragment. I get the data from Firebase on MainActivity and then pass that data to my target fragment. When I start the app, the fragment doesn't show the data from the database, but if I load another fragment and then back to target fragment it starts showing.

Main Activity Code:

```
package com.shariarunix.examiner;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String uniqueKey;
    private String userName, userEmail, userPhone, userCourse;
    List<StudentDataModel> sDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    BottomNavigationView navBottom;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Default Fragment
        loadFrag(HomeFragment.getInstance(userName, userCourse), 0);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+userName+" : "+userCourse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Add Operation on Bottom Navigation Bar
        navBottom = findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);
        navBottom.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home).setChecked(true);
        navBottom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.profile:
                        // Loading Profile Fragment
                        loadFrag(new ProfileFragment(), 1);
                        break;
                    case R.id.home:
                        // Load Home Fragment
                        loadFrag(HomeFragment.getInstance(userName,userCourse), 1);
                        break;
                    case R.id.resource:
                        // Load R
                        loadFrag(new ResourceFragment(sDataList), 1);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Resource", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bonk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    //Swapping Fragment
    public void loadFrag(Fragment fragment, int flag){
        FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction();

        if (flag == 0){
            fragTrans.add(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment);
        }else{
            fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment);
        }
        fragTrans.commit();
    }
    // Load Data from database
    public void loadData(){
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("Student's Data").child(uniqueKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                sDataList.clear();
                StudentDataModel sData = snapshot.getValue(StudentDataModel.class);
                assert sData != null;
                userName = sData.getName();
                userEmail = sData.getEmail();
                userPhone = sData.getPhone();
                userCourse = sData.getCourse();
                sDataList.add(sData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hoy nai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        uniqueKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("uniqueKey");
        loadData();
    }
}
```

````
Fragment Code:


package com.shariarunix.examiner;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String U_NAME = "uName";
    private static final String U_COURSE = "uCourse";
    private String uName, uCourse;
    public HomeFragment(){
        //Default Empty Constructor
    }
    public static HomeFragment getInstance(String uName, String uCourse){
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(U_NAME, uName);
        bundle.putString(U_COURSE, uCourse);

        homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return homeFragment;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        TextView txtShowName = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_show_name_home);

        AppCompatButton btnExamReadMore = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_exam_read_more);

        if (getArguments()!= null){
            uName = getArguments().getString(U_NAME);
            uCourse = getArguments().getString(U_COURSE);
        }
        txtShowName.setText(uName);

        btnExamReadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ExamInfoActivity.class));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

I expect it to show the data immediately when I start the app.
````

Comment: Did you try to read the data from the Realtime Database directly into your fragment?

Comment: @AlexMamo No, I want to use the data in all of my fragment, that's why i read the data in MainActivity.

Comment: Why don't want that?

Comment: @AlexMamo Don't know why. But I think that will be complex. But surely i'll try this..
For now how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you simply call `loadFrag(HomeFragment.getInstance(userName, userCourse), 0);` from your `onDataChange()` method in loadData()?

Comment: @JornRigter let me try this, But i've call the loadData() method in onStart() method.

Comment: Yes, but in onStart() your data might not have loaded yet

Comment: @JornRigter yeah, but when i call the loadData() in onCreate , my app crashes.

Comment: Well I guess that's a different issue? Could you add the stack trace here so I can have a look for you?

Comment: what is stack trace? I don't know.